# MySQL with bind-address - possible to create an ip exception?

Tags: mysql, ssh

If you set the `bind-address` to `127.0.0.1` in `my.cnf` is there any way to manually allow connections from a specific ip address?

Mostly my database is accessed by the server it is hosted on, but I also want to be able to access the database directly from an office through an odbc connector. Is it possible to specify an exception? or is an ssh tunnel the only viable way to connect to the database once `bind-address` has been set?

(I'm trying to avoid having to set up an ssh tunnel on each of the machines in the office).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bind-address` specifies the *local* ip address of your mysql server, it doesn't have to do anything with its *remote* address (where it can be connected from).

Your address (starting with `192.168`) is a local net address, which means, it can be connected only from your local network. It is a very simple way for a localnet mysql *and* gateway server to make mysql available exclusively into the direction of your local network.

But it can't provide any filtering based on the *remote* address on the connections.

This binding thing is actually a setting of the linux (unix) kernel: creating a socket, this time, the listening TCP port 3306 of your mysql daemon, it can be set, on which interface can it wait connections. By default it is connectable on all of them.

This is because *you can't do from your mysql config*, what you want. But you have two better options:

1. You could allow mysql connection to everybody (using `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`, or entirely commenting out this line). After that, you could use `iptables` to limit the possible connector addresses (in this case, to your local network and to the outer ip of your friend).
2. You could limit the possible mysql connectors using the mysqls own security mechanism. It is a host-based authentication of the mysql server. Google for "mysql grant host".

(1) is more secure, but (2) doesn't require for you to learn iptables.

Comment: So, just to be clear, if I wanted to follow your second suggestion and use GRANTS to specify hosts for users, I would first have to revoke all privileges for the users (the host is currently set as '%') and then reapply the privileges making sure to specify the ip I want as the host?

Comment: @jessenorton Not exactly, in the main mysql table are different rule-sets for the hosts and for the users. I don't know exactly, how they interact, but maybe if you ask this as a new question, you will get excellent answer(s). Anyways, I suggest to be careful, or you could soon start to formulate your third question about the topic ("I closed out myself from my mysql, how can I get back"). :-) Here it is not a problem, if you create multiple questions about similar topics, until they are different and can be answered independently.

Answer (score 2):

You have to setup port-forwarding via `ssh` tunnel.

While `mysql` listening on the `127.0.0.1:3306`, you have to create the forwarding link:

```
ssh -f user@your-server.tld -L localhost:3306:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
```

Then you can connect to the `mysql` on the `localhost:3306` just like as it was launched on your local machine. All connections to the `localhost:3306` will be forwarded via encrypted link to the `127.0.0.1:3306` on the `your-server.tld`. Here I've used synonims `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` to tell the client from the server.

Only those users who have valid account on the `your-server.tld` can connect to the `mysql` server regardless of their IP-address. You can easily create a number of tunnels to the different servers.

```
ssh -f user1@your-server1.tld -L localhost:3306:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
ssh -f user2@your-server2.tld -L localhost:3307:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
ssh -f user3@your-server3.tld -L localhost:3308:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
```